# Почему правила пунктуации (современные и 1956 года) имеют разную структуру?

Tags: общие-вопросы

**Правилам орфографии и пунктуации – 60 лет.**  (Свод правил был сдан в набор 9 мая, подписан в печать 19 июля и опубликован в августе 1956 года – к началу нового учебного года).

**И вопрос:** Почему в Правилах 1956 года раздел "Пунктуация" **имеет структуру, отличную от современных правил**?

В 1956 году для каждого знака (запятая, тире, двоеточие и т.д.) приводились грамматические примеры, в то время как сейчас сначала задается грамматика, а затем объясняется выбор знаков препинания для каждой темы?

**Есть ли в этом какой-нибудь смысл и какой вариант лучше?**

Answer (score 1):

Если кратко, то сразу два вопроса. Что такое "структура"? И что такое "Современные Правила"? Это риторический вопрос, он же и ответ.

А если подробно, то есть единственный вариант - Правила-56. Других в природе не существует. Все остальное - в лучшем случае некие методические материалы. Но и их надо называть конкретно, а не "современными правилами".

Правила-56 действуют, к ним даже ничего не добавлено, ничего не убрано. Какая еще структура? Вы простите, но уже который раз замечаю, что тут некоторые живут в мире каких-то собственных представлений. Если это что-то опять связанное с лопатинским творчеством, то при всем уважении к Орфографической Комиссии (искренним), называть её труд современными правилами, противопоставляя их П-56, трижды неправильно.  Её, комиссии, предложения, во-первых, не были никем утверждены даже на уровне рекомендаций РАН, во-вторых, не декларировались как что-то заменяющее или отменяющее существующие базовые правила, в-третьих, пунктуации они вообще не касались.

После обсуждения установлено, что автор не понимает собственного вопроса. 
Ни о каком подобном сравнении "структур" Правил-56 и пособий по их изучению не может быть и речи. Правила, что в изложении Лопатина, что Розенталя не имеют "законодательной" силы. Их надо сравнивать с аналогичными изданиями.

Кстати, "Струтура", если не вкладывать в это слово какое-то умозрительное значение, у Правил и пособий в общем-то та же. Знак - правила использования. Другой и быть не может. Ну разве идти от ситуаций, но это это путь академической грамматически. а не орфографического (включая пунктуацию) справочника, каковым является издание Лопатина.

Comment: Вопрос конкретный: откройте Правила 1956 года, и увидите, как составлен текст: точка, запятая, тире, двоеточие. Откройте любой учебник, а также правил Лопатина или Розенталя, и увидите темы: тире между подлежащим и сказуемым, однородные члены, обособленные члены и т.д. Почему такая разница, этот вопрос принципиальный или нет, можно ли  правила Лопатина или Розенталя составить таким же образом?

Comment: И по поводу Правил 1956 года. Для практических нужд их не используют (они и не были составлены в виде учебного пособия). Эти правила нуждаются не в изменении содержания, а в редактировании текста для удобства чтения.

Comment: *Вопрос конкретный: откройте Правила 1956 года, и увидите, как составлен текст: точка, запятая, тире, двоеточие. Откройте любой учебник,* - А зачем сравнивать учебник со кодексом? Откройте учебник шестидесятых годов - Бархударава и Крючкова, хотя бы. С ними и сравнивайте Лопатина. а вы предлагаете сравнивать, условно говоря, таблицу Менделеева и  учебник химии. Или там, план счетов бухучета и методы финансового регулирования.

Comment: *(они и не были составлены в виде учебного пособия).* - ну вот понимаете же всё.Зачем тогда такие вопросы задаете?

Comment: К сожалению, Вы не понимаете, о чем речь. Современный учебник по пунктуации - это практически справочник по синтаксису, ведь популярных учебных пособий по грамматике нет. И вот там вперемешку с грамматическими сведениями УПОМИНАЮТСЯ и знаки препинания.  ОБЩАЯ ФУНКЦИЯ  трех основных знаков  абсолютна не видна, в то время как в Правилах 1956 года каждый знак рассматривается отдельно. Так составителям показалось удобнее, а ничего случайного нет.

Comment: Но современным пользователям даже сам вопрос кажется праздным, потому что они привыкли заучивать много-много правил  пунктуации по учебнику, который  так не называется..  Сейчас в  школе примерно такая же ситуация: вместо ботаники, зоологии, химии, физики введут одну дисциплину "Окружающий мир", а вместо классических уроков - презентации на тему. Вот и всё образование.

Comment: @Sibylla мне тоже вопрос кажется совершенно праздным, ибо он некорректен. И я это пытаюсь Вам объяснить, а Вы все свое  гнете. Наверное, я для вас слишком современен.

Comment: (О Вас у меня сложилось определенное мнение, но вряд ли здесь возможно его озвучить). К сожалению, Вы не можете мне объяснить некорректность вопроса, но попробуйте еще раз. Некорректный вопрос на данном сайте - это такой вопрос, который имеет следующие признаки (1, 2, 3...). По признаку N мой вопрос некорректный.  Хотя бесполезно всё это.

Comment: И по поводу современности (если сравнивать ее с 1956 годом). Чем дальше Вы от 1956 года, тем привычнее для Вас писать по правилам. Чем дальше Вы от Розенталя и ближе к Лопатину, тем труднее Вам понять логику русского письма, наверное, современному обществу придется открывать эту логику заново, люди о ней просто не подозревают, видят только правила и ничего, кроме правил).